# CakePHP search function with json

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm just getting started with CakePHP and bumped in to some problems.
I have this search function for searching two tables in a mysql database (Artist and ArtistSurname) that looks like this:

```
class ArtistsController extends AppController {
public function search ($search) {
    if ($search){
    $artists = $this->Artist->find('all', array('conditions' => array("surname like '%$search%' AND Artist.id = ArtistSurname.artist_id OR firstname like '%$search%' AND Artist.id = ArtistSurname.artist_id"), 'limit' => 400, 'fields' => array('Artist.firstname', 'ArtistSurname.surname', 'Artist.dbirth', 'Artist.id')));
    if (!$artists){
        throw new NotFoundException(__('No search result.'));
    }
    $result = array();
    foreach ($artists as $artist) {
    $fetchedArtist = array('value' => $artist['ArtistSurname']['surname'] . " " . $artist['Artist']['firstname'], 'year' => $artist['Artist']['dbirth'], 'id' => $artist['Artist']['id']);
    array_push($result, $fetchedArtist);
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($result);
    $this->autoRender = false;
    }
}
```

After the query I put my result in a new readable array for my autocomplete(typeahead.js) and 
echo this as json. This works fine as long as the query finds a firstname but not if the query only finds surnames. The strange thing is that I only recieve application/json from my GET request when a firstname is found otherwise I'm getting the correct result in text/html. Why is this?

Comment: For the json part you want to read this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Answer (score 2):

You are using a separate table to store Surname and basically constructing an `INNER JOIN` by specifying `Artist.id = ArtistSurname.artist_id` as part of your condition (twice).

Also you're defining the conditions the wrong way; you should be using 'array' notation for each condition/field so that CakePHP will properly escape values for you;

```
$artists = $this->Artist->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
         'OR' => array(   
             'ArtistSurname.surname LIKE' => '%' . $search . '%',
             'Artist.firstname LIKE' =>  '%' . $search . '%',
         )
    ),
    joins => array(
        array(
          'table' => 'artist_surnames',
          'alias' => 'ArtistSurname',
          'type' => 'LEFT',
          'conditions' => array(
              'Artist.id = ArtistSurname.artist_id',
          )
       ),
    ),
    'limit' => 400, 
    'fields' => array(
        'Artist.firstname', 
        'ArtistSurname.surname',
        'Artist.dbirth',
        'Artist.id'
     )
));
```

I converted the ArtistSurname <-> Artist relation to a 'LEFT' join so that results will also be returned if no 'surname' was found.

Normally, you don't have to manually specify these relations in your query, but specify them in your model relations (ArtistSurname->belongsTo->Artist):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#associations-linking-models-together

However, I tried to stay as close to your original functionality as possible.

**why** are you using a separate Model for the surname of an artist? I can think of no reason to make this so complicated?

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Worked like a charm! This is an old db that I'm building a new website for, and the surname table is just one of many strange solutions. I was planning on rebuild the whole db but I'm not allowed by the customer to change anything unfortunately. "Why change it when it works?" He says.. Have to work with what I got I guess..

Comment: Well, tell the customer that in this case there is a design-flaw that needs to be fixed. In its current form, an Artist is allowed to have multiple surnames. Because of the join, the same Artist may be shown multiple times with another surname?

Comment: LOL, and it's probably best to deliver the source code of your finished product to your customer by printing it out. Tell them you're doing so because paper is a proven technology and you didn't make the switch to 'Internet' - why change? Paper still works! (Sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: I will tell him that, I actually wrote a script in node.js that reads the artist_surnames table and creates a new table with both firstname and surname but he still says no, a stubborn old man.. The problem is that he has worked with the same solution now for like 10 years and he's afraid that if change his cardhouse everything will fall apart.

Comment: Even better, morse is a proven encryption technology!